# How to insert multiple (2) javascript files into html page

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page, and I have these 2 files I want to insert.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Request.js"  ></script>
```

```js
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

var saveReservation = function() {
    
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    sessionStorage.setItem("name", name);
 var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    sessionStorage.setItem("email", email);
 
 
 
    // submit form
    $("reservation_form").submit();
};

window.onload = function() {
    $("submit_request").onclick = saveReservation;
    $("arrival_date").focus();
};
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="regex.js" ></script>
```

```js
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

var validatePhone = function() {
    var phone = $("phone").value;
    var pattern = /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/;                        // 999-999-9999
    
    
    var pattern = /^(1[-\.\s])?(\()?\d{3}(\))?[-\.\s]\d{3}[-\.]\d{4}$/;
    
    
    var isValid = pattern.test(phone);
    
    $("message").firstChild.nodeValue = (isValid) ? "Valid phone number" : "Invalid phone number";
};

window.onload = function() {
    $("validate").onclick = validatePhone;
};
```

One of them takes you to session storage when a button is clicked, and the other validates a phone number when the button is clicked.

However, when I just used that script above, it just runs one or the other.

Comment: Some people are VERY good at JS here, but none are mind readers. How do you expect us to help without ANY code? Do you call the functions the same or use window.onload?

Comment: Can't you use one file for your javascript if you are getting some errors you don't know about?

Comment: @DamienGold Why would they want to? Unless you're minifying your code, it's best to keep separate concerns in separate files.

Comment: If you include js files in the code like the way you are showing above, they will execute in that same order

Comment: Both files are setting `window.onload`.  That's your problem.  Both files are running just fine.  You can prove this to yourself by adding a `console.log('hi')` to each.  You're using jquery, but you aren't attaching to the `load` event correctly.

Comment: You can't go `window.onload += ...` in JavaScript, can you?

Comment: Ha - I was mind reading anyway ;) - use addEventListener or jQuery

Comment: If I were you, I would use jQuery. It would make life (coding, debugging, ...) easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

Each one sets `window.onload=`, so when one runs, it replaces the onload handler of the other. One thing you can do, if you don't want to take on a dependency on something like jQuery, is something like this, whereby you check first to see if an onload handler is already set, and if so, add your new one and call the existing one:

```
if (window.onload) {
    oldOnload = window.onload;
    window.onload = function() {
        myOnload();
        oldOnload();
    }
} else {
    window.onload = myOnload();
}
```

Where `myOnload` is whatever function you're trying to set. Do this in both files, and neither will step on the toes of the other. You could also put all this in a function so you can just call e.g. `setOnload(myFunc)` to safely set/add onload as above. You can use this technique to add as many onload handlers as you need to.

Comment: Why not just use `addEventListener()`?

Comment: You can, depending on your browser targets. Older browsers (particularly older IE browsers) don't offer full (or any) support for `addEventListener`.

Comment: I was just writing a similar function, and found that if you add more than two onload events a Maximum call stack size exceeded exception occurs. Did you experience that?


`function addOnLoad(newFunction){
 oldOnLoad = window.onload;
 window.onload = typeof oldOnLoad === "function" ? function(){oldOnLoad();newFunction()} : newFunction
}`

Comment: @Amy no, he doesn't appear to be: `var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };` is right there in both his source files.